# How to get current current cursor position of terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, console

I'm making Tetris game in C. This game have to work on Linux.
I need to get current cursor position to return them.
I don't want to use curses and ncurses.

```
point GetCurrentCursorPos(void)
{
  point curPoint;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO curInfo;

  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &curInfo);
  curPoint.x=curInfo.dwCursorPosition.X;
  curPoint.y=curInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;

  return curPoint;
 }
```

Here's the code I want to change.

and point struct looks like this.

```
typedef struct __point 
{
   int x;
   int y; 
} point;
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use  `ncurses`. And if you still don't, study its source code carefully to mimic it (which IMHO could be a big loss of your development time).

Comment: BTW, did you consider making some [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application, in practice using some toolkit like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) ?

Comment: Read also [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's because teacher wanted not to use it. Sadly, I don't have experience using GTK and Qt. I just started learning Linux and everything is so confuse.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch BTW, Thank you for the links!

Comment: Your teacher requires you to make a tetris game without external libraries? If yes, that should go into the question (and you would spend several months on such a project). Notice that [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) such as [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) were complex devices, so [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)s are quite complex too... Be aware of [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Read also [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf). Be aware that your "tetris game on Linux terminal emulator without external libraries" project is probably *much harder* than what you believe. Consider discussing with your teacher about it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can't use curses and ncurses only. I think teacher want us to handle something like "\e[%d;%dR". I have one more question. I'm just curious that, if there's error saying  ex) '<curses.h> : there's no such file or directory', do I have to install the library to use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use (n)curses, you're stuck interfacing with the terminal directly. You can use the VT100 DSR sequence to request a cursor position report -- write the characters

```
"\e[6n"
```

to the terminal, and it will reply with a sequence similar to:

```
"\e[12;34R"
```

indicating that the cursor is at row 12, column 34 (for example). The sequence is sent inline with user input, so you may need to take special precautions to avoid consuming user input while trying to get the cursor location…

Needless to say, this is a clumsy interface to work with, and you are really better off avoiding needing it in the first place. Keep track of the cursor's location in code and you won't need to ask the terminal where it is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can I get x and y position separately from that? I want to set struct curPoint like curPoint.x = x and curPoint.y = y in this function.

Comment: Could be more complex than that, e.g. with [termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) since it is not sure that every terminal is VT100 compatible (even if in practice that is very likely)

Comment: Is it possible to get the maximal allowed position, ie the terminal's resolution?